# product of cosine and sine functions into sum of sine functions transformation

Tags: trigonometry

I'm required to transform this expression by using elementary trigonometric functions into sum of sine functions. Any help or hints would be welcome.

> $$m_e = -2I_1I_2L_d\cos(\omega_1 t)\cdot\cos(\omega_2 t+\alpha)\cdot\sin(\omega_m t+\delta)$$

/// EDIT: ***RESULT*** [image]

Comment: What is the motivation behind this question? Where did you encounter it? What are your own thoughts on how to solve it?

Comment: @Math1000 Dear Math1000 the upper expression is a mathematical way to describe electromagnetic moment inside special type of electric machine. For deeper analysis of that very machine, this expression must be transformed into sum of sine functions. It is known that the final result consists of four elements which are all sine functions. I've tried separating this product with elementary trig transformations but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write the expression to be transformed in the following way :

$$m_e = -2I_1I_2L_d\cos(\omega_1 t)\cdot\cos(\omega_2 t+\alpha)\cdot\cos(\omega_m t+\delta-\frac{\pi}{2})$$

Let us use the following formula :

> $$\eqalign{&\cos x\cos y\cos z\cr &\qquad=\tfrac{1}{4}\bigl(\cos(x+y+z)+\cos(x+y-z)+\cos(y+z-x)+\cos(z+x-y)\bigr)\ .\cr}$$

(see for example (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2640161)) :

$$m_e=-\tfrac{1}{2}I_1I_2L_d\bigl[\cos((\omega_1+\omega_2+\omega_m) t+\alpha+\delta-\tfrac{\pi}{2})+\underbrace{\cos((\omega_1+\omega_2-\omega_m)t+\alpha-\delta+\tfrac{\pi}{2})}_{=\cos(-(\omega_1+\omega_2-\omega_m)t-\alpha+\delta-\tfrac{\pi}{2}) \ \text{using parity}}+\cos((-\omega_1+\omega_2+\omega_m)t+\alpha+\delta-\tfrac{\pi}{2})+\cos((\omega_1-\omega_2+\omega_m)t-\alpha+\delta-\tfrac{\pi}{2})\bigr]$$

It suffices now to use the classical formula

$$\cos(A-\tfrac{\pi}{2})=\sin(A)$$

to obtain the result you gave.

Answer (score 1):

Note,

$$2\cos(\omega_1 t)\cos(\omega_2 t+\alpha)
=\cos[(\omega_1+\omega_2)t+\alpha]+\cos[(\omega_2-\omega_1)t+\alpha]$$

$$2\cos[(\omega_1+\omega_2)t+\alpha] \sin(\omega_m t+\delta)$$
$$=\sin[(\omega_1+\omega_2+\omega_m)t+\alpha+\delta]-\sin[(\omega_1+\omega_2-\omega_m)t+\alpha-\delta]$$

$$2\cos[(\omega_2-\omega_1)t+\alpha] \sin(\omega_m t+\delta)$$
$$=\sin[(\omega_2-\omega_1+\omega_m)t+\alpha+\delta]-\sin[(\omega_2-\omega_1-\omega_m)t+\alpha-\delta]$$

Comment: the final result is shown in the edit of my post. Somehow I'm missing two addends. Am I missing something?

Comment: @kenobe - looks right to me.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Use the linearisation formulæ:
\begin{cases}\begin{aligned}
\cos a \cos b&=\tfrac12\bigl(\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)\bigr),\\
\sin a \cos b&=\tfrac12\bigl(\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)\bigr).
\end{aligned}\end{cases}